# PHPUnit getMock() with namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

My quest of starting to use namespaces in PHP keeps continuing. This time PHPUnit gives me problems. My setup() method is like this:

```
$test = new \MyNamespace\NonPersistentStorage(); // works
$mock = $this->getMock('\\MyNamespace\\NonPersistentStorage'); // doesn't work
```

The getMock() method only results in PHP looking for a NonPersistentStorage class. Not within the namespace.

Q: What do I need to change to get the getMock() method look for the class in the namespace?

Edit: The double backslash is not the problem. Also see: [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.quote): (quote)

'Inside a single-quoted string, the backslash escape sequence is much safer to use, but it is still recommended practice to escape backslashes in all strings as a best practice.'

edit: What worked for me is in the comments of the answer of Ignace R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String references to classes generally don't have the leading backslash. Try removing it and tell us if it works.

**EDIT:** and if it doesn't, try [class_alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) to create an alias in the global namespace for that class. However, that would be an ugly solution...

Comment: Well, by "leading backslash" I meant both leading backslashes, but I hope you understood it anyway.

Comment: Try the class_alias workaround then (in case you didn't notice the edit).

Comment: Thought this worked: class_alias('\\MyNamespace\\NonPersistentStorage', 'NonPersistentStorage'); $mock = $this->getMock('NonPersistentStorage');

but it gives a 'cannot redeclare class' error. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: It seems that everything is done correctly in your example. But which statement of these two actually throws the error? Is it the class_alias call or the getMock one?

Comment: class_alias. Reversing the names gives the same error as before. The problems is I think in the PHPUnit mock code: class PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Mock, line 132 of the file is:
$isClass     = class_exists($className, $callAutoload);

This calls my autoload function which doesn't find it. But $className starts as the same string one gives in getMock('className'), but the namespace part is removed. So I guess the solution would be to manually include the file.

Comment: Ofcourse requiring doesn't work. Still loads the file in a different namespace.

Comment: Well, there should be no problems with autoloading. If a class is already accessible, then it's not autoloaded. Your problem looks strange... Maybe you could try aliasing the class to a completely different name, or removing the getMock call at all and seeing if the aliasing still causes problems.

Comment: Also, if you import that class before aliasing, that might be causing the problem. Try removing the "use" statement if it actually exists.

Comment: I've solved it with your suggestion of removing the \\ at the start + changing my autoload (added if file_exists before require_once)
Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

use this string instead (without the double backslashes):

```
$mock = $this->getMock('\MyNamespace\NonPersistentStorage');
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that you can solve your problem including the class \MyNamespace\NonPersistentStorage in your test file.

Comment: I think that you are missing the whole point of mocking classes.