# PHPUnit: stub methods undefined

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I must be missing something. I'm trying to stub methods on a class in PHPUnit, but when I invoke the method on the mock object, it tells me that method is undefined.

Example class to stub:

```
namespace MyApp;

class MyStubClass 
{
   public function mrMethod()
   {
     // doing stuff
   }   
}
```

To stub it, I write:

```
// specifying all getMock() args to disable calling of class __construct()
$stub = $this->getMock('MyStubClass', array(), array(), 'MockMyStubClass', false, false, false);
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('mrMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('doing stuff'));
```

But upon invoking the stubbed method, I get an exception:

```
$stub->mrMethod();
//PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MockMyStubClass::mrMethod()
```

I'm using PHPUnit 3.4.3 with PHP 5.3.0.

Another small thing I noticed was that if specifying a namespace in the `getMock()` method results in a class loading exception because of a double namespace:

```
$stub = $this->getMock('MyApp\MyStubClass');
// Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\MyApp\MyStubClass' not found
```

That strikes me as rather odd (and getmock() will not accept a namespace with a leading backslash). The only thing I could think to cause that would may be because this class is
registered with an autoloader?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answering my own question:

After quite a bit of frustration, I did manage to get things working. I'm not sure precisely what the issue was, but did discover a few things that might help others:

- Make sure you're running the latest version of PHPUnit (3.4.6 as of this writing)
- Use the fully-qualified namespace minus the first backslash.

  ```
  $this->getMock('MyApp\Widgets\WidgetFactory');
  ```

Part of my problem was that PHPUnit was creating a stub class `WidgetFactory` that was not actually stubbing `MyApp\Widgets\WidgetFactory`. One would expect that an exception would occur if trying to stub a non-existent class, but it doesn't seem to happen with the namespace confusion.

Also, there is a question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262083/phpunit-getmock-with-namespace) that suggests using the class alias method as follows:

```
    class_alias('MyApp\Widgets\WidgetFactory', 'WidgetFactory');
    $this->getMock('WidgetFactory');
```

While this did temporarily solve my problem, I would strongly advise against using it. `class_alias()` cannot be called twice for the same alias without raising an exception, which causes obvious problem if used in the `setup()` method, or as part of the stub generation.

Comment: Very useful -- had no idea (apparently, a bit naive of me) that the original class was needed to be accessed to mock it.

Comment: "Use the fully-qualified namespace minus the first backslash." -- This is what got me :)

Comment: this answer is very useful! I used phpunit 4.8.16, php 5.3. And below is worked.  
`$stub_obj = $this->getMockBuilder('MyApp\Controller\Convert\MyClass')->getMock();`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my problem was that the path I was writing was something like `MyApp\Widgets\WidgetFactory\MyStubClass` while the class was something like this:

```
namespace MyApp;

class MyStubclass 
{
   public function mrMethod()
   {
     // doing stuff
   }   
}
```

So there wasn't the uppercase C in the name of the class in the path